# How do I automatically proceed from one Alexa skills intent to another intent when a user answers yes?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to make the following possible.

User: "Alexa, open coffee shop"

Alexa: "Welcome to coffee shop! Would you like to know our hours of operation?"

U: "Yes"

Alexa: "We are open 9-5"

OR

U: "No"

Alexa: "Ok, have a good day!"

I have tried eliciting slots, delegating directives, and confirming intents. None seem to have worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
    const LaunchRequestHandler = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
        },
        handle(handlerInput) {
            const speakOutput = 'Welcome to coffee shop! Would you like to know our hours of operation?';

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speakOutput)
                .addConfirmIntentDirective({
                    name: 'OperationalHoursIntent',
                    confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
                    slots: {}
                })
                .getResponse();
        }
    };

    const OperationalHoursHandler = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'OperationalHoursIntent';
        },
        handle(handlerInput) {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak('we are open 9-5.')
                .reprompt('we are open 9-5.')
                .getResponse();
        }
    };
```

What am I missing? I am not sure if my model is setup incorrectly or if something is borked with my dialog delegation. I have disabled autodelegation. What should my model look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without custom dialogs using the built-in intents `AMAZON.YesIntent` and `AMAZON.NoIntent`.  It gets messy if you are asking different Yes/No questions all over your skill, because you then need to keep track of the context.  But for this use case it's quite straightforward.

In `LaunchRequestHandler`, set a new session attribute, e.g. `offeredOpeningHours` to `true`.  This will act as a flag for your `YesIntent` handler.

Add `AMAZON.YesIntent` to your model.  In its handler, check if your `offeredOpeningHours` is present and `true`.  If  so, return your operational hours prompt.  Whether it was true or not, delete it to avoid confusion if you catch another 'Yes' later in a different context.

For completeness, also implement `AMAZON.NoIntent` and just delete the attribute before asking what they want to do next.

As with any intent, you should always end your response with a question or let them know you're ending the session, e.g. 'We're open nine till five. What else can I help with?'